# Breaking up a string(2011-09-10) with PHP

Tags: php, date

I'm passing a date value in the following format.

```
 2011-09-10
```

I need to break it into 3 variables using php.

```
$day = 
$month =  
$year =
```

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your case, [`$parts = explode("-", $inputstr);`](http://th.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) would work (and then year is `$parts[0]` et cetera).

But, for more general date parsing, you might want [`strptime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) (if you know the format) or [`strtotime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) (if you don't).

Answer (score 3):

In one line:

```
list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', '2011-09-10');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$date = getdate(strtotime("2011-09-10"));

print_r($date);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [seconds] => 0
    [minutes] => 0
    [hours] => 0
    [mday] => 10
    [wday] => 6
    [mon] => 9
    [year] => 2011
    [yday] => 252
    [weekday] => Saturday
    [month] => September
    [0] => 1315612800
)
```

Answer (score -1):

See PHP's [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function